# Android application prevents device from locking screen and sleeping

Tags: android, wakelock

My Android application being created by Android Studio now unintentionally prevents my Galaxy device from locking screen and sleeping. Requested permissions are following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Earlier I included permission

```
<!--<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>-->
```

but now this line is commented. Only `INTERNET` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`permissions are now requested. I tried to explicitly remove (uninstall) my application from device and install it again, but the application (when launched and being active) doesn't allow the device to sleep. When other app is active (my application is launched but inactive) the device comes to sleep in defined time.
The application use `PendingIntent`, `Broadcast` and `AlarmManager` classes, but the device doesn't sleep even if no method of these classes are called. `WakeLock` class **is not used**.

AndroidManifest.xml is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="spectorsky.timer">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>-->
    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="spectorsky.timer.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="MyAlarmReceiver" />
    </application>
```

Here is the receiver class:

```
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public MyAlarmReceiver() {
        super();
        }

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            int channelNumber=intent.getIntExtra("channelNumber",13);
            String ipAddress=intent.getStringExtra("ipAddress");
            int nChannel=intent.getIntExtra("nChannel",13);
            intent.getParcelableExtra("messenger");
            new TVTimerAsync(ipAddress,nChannel,m, context).execute(MainActivity.digitReader(channelNumber));
        }  
}
```

And here is code invoking BroadCast:

```
MyIntent myIntentAlarm;
int myIntentId=0;
AlarmManager myAlarmManager;
```

...................

```
 myAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, d.getTime(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, myIntentId++,
                   myIntentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT));
```

Thanks in advance for any idea.

PS There are many posts about such problem, but I couldn't find something like my case.

Comment: please provide your manifest file and also check if there is any code related to wake lock permission programmatically mentioned.

Comment: without more code snippets of your app we can only guess whats your problem here..

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml has been added. The only things in the code which might relate to wake lock is `PendingIntent`, `Broadcast` and `AlarmManager` classes. However, even if I just launch app and no methods of these classes are performed, devices cannot come to sleep. Should I provide onCreate of my main activity? It is of 85 lines...

Comment: Show your receiver class and show the code where sendBroadcast is called

Comment: Thanks everybody who are trying to to help. Receiver class has been added. I don't use `sendBroadcast`, Created `Intent` is invoked by setting `PendingIntent` in `AlarmManager`. By the way, is it possible to place big parts of code in my question in some vertical scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned almost everything in the project: the application restored sleeping ability after deleting `android:keepScreenOn` attribute in `ListView` definition:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listIntents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

> `android:keepScreenOn="true"`

```
        android:scrollIndicators="right"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:textFilterEnabled="false"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/deleteChosen">

</ListView>
```

I did hope that this attribute make the list to remain in front of other controls, and it will never be hidden. However, the meaning appeared to be quite different: 'keep on screen' means the screen always turn on.

Thanks to everybody for trying help